# How to increase step table output performance in pentaho with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, database, postgresql, etl, pentaho

Good morning guys,
I have a problem with the step table output of pentaho.
I'm reading a .csv file with 80 million lines and saving it in a table in postgreSQL.
However, it is taking a long time for the pentaho table output step to save the data.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this? Is there any setting in Pentaho or PostgreSQL that increases the performance of data output